# How to make repeating column values empty in python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working in a pandas dataframe in python and my output now looks like the following:

```
1     abc     19
1     def     14
1     efg     9
2     abc     30
2     def     2
2     efg     5
```

etc...

I want to change my pandas to make it look like this:

```
1     abc     19
      def     14
      efg     9
2     abc     30
      def     2
      efg     5
```

etc...

Could anybody help me out? Thanks a lot in advance!

To clarify: The output above is already a result from groupby() and set_index().
The code was :

```
df_2 = df_1.reset_index().sort_values(["col_1","col_2"],ascending=False).set_index("col_1","col_2")
```

if I now do groupby or set_index, it returns an error

Comment: `df.set_index([1st_col_name, 2nd_col_name])`?

Comment: use [pandas.DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {'A': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 'B':[i for i in range(6)], 'C': [i for i in  range(10, 16)]}  
x = pd.DataFrame(d)    
x.set_index(['A', 'B'])
```